# apt update looks for source not listed in sources.list or sources.list.d or anywhere in /etc/apt/

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade, updates, ppa

In Ubuntu Studio 22.10 and 22.04.1 LTS Every time I run apt, especially apt update I find it has looked for a source that does not exist anywhere in /etc/apt/ directories or files therein.
At first this was just a puzzling irritant but now Ubuntu Studio Discovery is delayed as much as 3 minutes opening apparently looking for the same source.

```
$ sudo apt update
Hit:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu kinetic InRelease
Hit:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu kinetic-updates InRelease
Get:3 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu kinetic-backports InRelease [99.9 kB]
Hit:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu kinetic-security InRelease
Ign:5 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu kinetic InRelease
Err:6 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu kinetic Release            <<---!!
  404  Not Found [IP: 2620:2d:4000:1003::111 80]
Hit:7 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/tatokis/alarm-clock-applet/ubuntu kinetic InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu kinetic Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
```

I tried the various recommendations for sudo ppa-purge and sudo apt-get install ppa-purge and received results indicating they failed because they could not find the package to purge.

Checking "Software Sources" I found this source was not listed under any of the tabs.
I then looked in each directory and file in /etc/apt/ and again found no sign of this
"http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu kinetic Release"

So the questions are
"Where is apt finding the directive to look for this?"
and
"How do I remove it, so apt does not continue looking for it?"

Below is a log of the directories and files I searched to confirm that "http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu kinetic Release" is not listed in the Ubuntu Sources or in /etc/apt/.

Contents of apt sources.list

```
$ inxi -r
Repos:
  Active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list
    1: deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ kinetic main restricted
    2: deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ kinetic-updates main restricted
    3: deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ kinetic universe
    4: deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ kinetic-updates universe
    5: deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ kinetic multiverse
    6: deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ kinetic-updates multiverse
    7: deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ kinetic-security main restricted
    8: deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ kinetic-security universe
    9: deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ kinetic-security multiverse
    10: deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ kinetic-backports main restricted universe multiverse
    11: deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/ kinetic partner
  Active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/tatokis-ubuntu-alarm-clock-applet-kinetic.list
    1: deb https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/tatokis/alarm-clock-applet/ubuntu/ kinetic main
```

I searched in /etc/apt/and sub directories
for http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu kinetic Release

```
g905:/etc/apt$ ls
apt.conf.d   keyrings       sources.list   sources.list.d  trusted.gpg.d
auth.conf.d  preferences.d  sources.list~  trusted.gpg
g905:/etc/apt$ cd trusted.gpg.d
g905:/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d$ ls
tatokis-ubuntu-alarm-clock-applet.gpg   ubuntu-keyring-2012-cdimage.gpg
tatokis-ubuntu-alarm-clock-applet.gpg~  ubuntu-keyring-2018-archive.gpg
g905:/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d$ cd ..
g905:/etc/apt$ ls
apt.conf.d   keyrings       sources.list   sources.list.d  trusted.gpg.d
auth.conf.d  preferences.d  sources.list~  trusted.gpg
g905:/etc/apt$ cd sources.list.d
g905:/etc/apt/sources.list.d$ ls
tatokis-ubuntu-alarm-clock-applet-kinetic.list
g905:/etc/apt/sources.list.d$ cd ..
g905:/etc/apt$ cd apt.conf.d
g905:/etc/apt/apt.conf.d$ ls
01autoremove     20archive   50appstream     60icons-large    99update-notifier
01-vendor-ubuntu 20auto-upgrades 50command-not-found   60icons-large-hidpi
10periodic       20dbus          50unattended-upgrades 70debconf
15update-stamp   20packagekit    60icons               88libdvdcss-pkg
20apt-esm-hook.conf 20snapd.conf 60icons-hidpi         99synaptic
g905:/etc/apt/apt.conf.d$ cd ..
g905:/etc/apt$ cd auth.conf.d
g905:/etc/apt/auth.conf.d$ ls [Empty]
g905:/etc/apt/auth.conf.d$ cd ..
g905:/etc/apt$ cd preferences.d
g905:/etc/apt/preferences.d$ ls [Empty]
g905:/etc/apt/preferences.d$ cd ..
```

Again to be clear; Where else can it be? and If more than just deleting the folder or file, How can I delete it.

```
Platform details
Operating System: Ubuntu Studio 22.10
KDE Plasma Version: 5.25.5 
KDE Frameworks Version: 5.98.0 Qt Version: 5.15.6 
Kernel Version: 5.19.0-1018-lowlatency (64-bit) 
Graphics Platform: X11 
Processors: 24 × AMD Ryzen 9 7900X 12-Core Processor  
Memory: 31.1 GiB of RAM  
Graphics Processor: llvmpipe 
Manufacturer: MicroElectronics Product Name: G905 System Version: 1.0
```

Comment: UN-clicking it In Software Sources removed it from the: /etc/apt/sources.list
Removing the "... has no release file"  error as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's the 11th repo in `/etc/apt/sources.list`  that causes trouble:

```
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/ kinetic partner
```

Comment out this line and try again.

Comment: UN-clicking it In Software Sources removed it from the: /etc/apt/sources.list
Removing the "... has no release file"  error as well.
 I mistakenly read "ubuntu/ kinetic partner " and "ubuntu kinetic Release" as the same thus searching for  
"No release file" fixes unnecessarily.
 I found the latter error message very misleading while you went straight to the point. Thank you.  It puzzles me that the two error messages do seem related but to what end was the latter generated?